# SQL Server Health Check and Performance Tuning

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-performance, health-monitoring

I have a database that was recreated each night with about 10 columns and 1,000,000 rows.  The data is completely deleted and re-inserted.

I have full text search on this table turned on and I rebuild it after each night.

Recently I noticed that my indexes get extremely fragmented by doing this.  Is rebuilding my indexes after each insert the solution to this?

I'm trying to speed up my search and filtering of the data, should I just rebuild the indexes each night as well as the full text index?

Is the fragmentation really slowing me down that much?

I'm also open to other ways to improve performance on this table on a nightly basis if you have any suggestions.

Comment: If everything else is being rebuilt, rebuilding the indexes wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Here's a MS source to check out: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189858.aspx

Comment: I know this is a horrible question, but a 10 column, million row database how long should it take to build an index?  I'm just looking for ball park (1 minute, 30 minute, 5 hours?)

Comment: That's really tough to guess, given the innumerable variables in any given environment.  But with 10 columns, 1M rows, I'd say probably less than 10 minutes.  Maybe 5.